# How to make a GameObject move some fixed units relative to itself via method call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I want is that the green point (this is a GameObject with a script attached) moves one red arrow of movement each time `MoveTile(Direction direction)` is called, e.q. `MoveTile(Direction.EAST);`

So, if at point A in time `MoveTile(Direction.EAST);` is called, and some time B `MoveTile(Direction.NORTH);` is called, you should get the following result:

[image: Explanatory image of movement]

The green dot currently has the following MonoBehaviour attached:

```
public class PlayerIndicator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum Direction { NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST }
    private static readonly int TILE_UNIT = 2;

    public void MoveTile(Direction direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.NORTH:
                // TODO move one TILE_UNIT up
                break;
            case Direction.EAST:
                // TODO move one TILE_UNIT right
                break;
            case Direction.SOUTH:
                // TODO move one TILE_UNIT down
                break;
            case Direction.WEST:
                // TODO move one TILE_UNIT left
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something along these lines may work for you: `float tileDist = 0.5f;` ... North: `transform.Translate(tileDist * Vector2.up);` East: `transform.Translate(tileDist * Vector2.right);` West: `transform.Translate(-tileDist * Vector2.right);` South: `transform.Translate(-tileDist * Vector2.up);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. By using coroutines in combination with a threshold check you can move until the desired location is reached.

```
public class PlayerIndicator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum Direction { NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST }
    private static readonly float SPEED = 1f;
    private static readonly float THRESHOLD = 0.01f;
    private static readonly float TILE_DISTANCE = 2f;

    private void Update()
    {
        // Fire coroutine, this can also be done with an event
        StartCoroutine(MoveTileOverTime(Direction.EAST));
    }

    public IEnumerator MoveTileOverTime(Direction direction)
    {
        Vector2 target = new Vector2();

        // Determine the target position, this is relative from the current position
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.NORTH:
                target = (Vector2) transform.position + Vector2.up * TILE_DISTANCE;
                break;
            case Direction.EAST:
                target = (Vector2) transform.position + Vector2.right * TILE_DISTANCE;
                break;
            case Direction.SOUTH:
                target = (Vector2) transform.position + Vector2.down * TILE_DISTANCE;
                break;
            case Direction.WEST:
                target = (Vector2) transform.position + Vector2.left * TILE_DISTANCE;
                break;
        }

        // Threshold check / stop condition
        while (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target) > THRESHOLD)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, Time.deltaTime * SPEED);
            // All coroutines MUST end with a yield
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }
}
```